# JS: Why does variable placement break my code?

Tags: javascript

I am trying a system where when you click a button, it turns into a `active` state. Then when you click other buttons on the screen, if your "active", another event will happen instead of the regular events.

I got it to work, but I am confused about something. This is the working code:

```
dom.el("skill").onclick = active;

 function active(){
    active = true;
 }

var active = false;
```

Placing the global variable `active` at the bottom of the list fixed the problem, but I initially had it at the very top, which DID NOT work.

```
var active = false;

dom.el("skill").onclick = active;

 function active(){
    active = true;
 }
```

Why does this one NOT work? To me they are practically the same, just in a different order.

Comment: A variable can't contain a function and a boolean at the same time.

Comment: Almost certainly due to the fact that variable and function have the same name; one time you're assigning false to the onclick, the other the function. Why not choose different names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the term "hoisting". It is because your function declaration is hoisted, therefore it is moved to the top. Initializations are not hoisted, so `var active = false` stays where you put it.

In the first case, the function declaration happens first, then you set the function to your onclick handler.

In the second case, you set `false` to the handler.

It might be a good idea to have different name for your variable and for your function.

Answer (score 1):

```
var active = false; dom.el("skill").onclick = function (){ active = true; }
```

Thus is how you should do it. Using the same variable for a function and a boolean will may work in some cases but its not a good style. Just dont do it.

Comment: "Using the same variable for a function and a boolean will may work in some cases": only in Ruby.